# How do applications such as HypeDNS resolve both custom and standard domains?

Tags: web, dns

If you didn't know, [HypeDNS](https://wiki.projectmeshnet.org/HypeDNS) is [an application written in Perl](http://svn.mg2.org/projects/pco/browser/trunk/net/node_info/script/hypedns.pl) that resolves .hype domains to Hyperboria nodes. What I want to know is how is resolves these custom .hype domains as well as resolving the standard ones too (.com, .net, .org etc.)

Comment: Maybe you can point me, which other applications exist that resolve such custom domains ?

Comment: @Sandman4 point taken. For some reason I was thinking of TOR hidden services at the time

Comment: Heh, I'm just innocently asking. I'm really interested to know if such apps exist. I think SocialVPN does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The server first looks for names stored in the NodeInfo database, and
>   if found, returns the address (or name if reversing!) post haste! If
>   the domain is not found, or it is a request for an A record (IPv4),
>   the query is forwarded on to ns03.mg2.org, or ns04.mg2.org, Mikey´s
>   local name servers.

Turns out that HypeDNS forwards DNS requests, meaning if it can't resolve the query, it will forward it to other servers and then return their response.

Comment: it's _forwarding_ , not _recursive_ - it **forwards** query to other servers, which do the recursion.